# Symbols that compose a word

Tags: english, corpora, written-language

Words contain letters (A to Z and a to z), but also apostrophes, such as in the case:

```
don't
```

and even:

```
'em
```

and even hyphens in the case of:

```
ice-cream
```

or:

```
long wind-
ed sentence
```

With regard to English, is there any other symbols that can compose a word? More precisely, I want to know how I should identify words when processing a corpus.

Additionally, I would be interested in learning about other European languages and their use of such symbols within words which fall outside those defined by the alphabet.

Comment: My experience with corpora and word counting is that all sorts of different definitions are used. A simple one is to count the spaces in a text (-1 and you have the number of words, provided all double spaces have been removed). I found that to be the best workable method. You could also use a lemmatizer and count the lemmas identified by it. Also, it's not uncommon to consider contractions like *don't* as two words. I haven't heard of any accepted standards, and in practice you just have to watch out that you compare like with like.

Comment: The "definition of word" problem also leads to "Is 'Hong' a word?' As in "Hong Kong". Is "tit-for-tat" one word or three? What about "vis-a-vis"? These are basically things you need to decide for your needs and based on the capabilities of your tools.

Comment: In my code I always have a set of extra characters to treat as parts of words always plus for each language I optionally define a set of extra characters. And even this is not enough since both apostrophes and single quote marks are the same character and are not straightforward to disambiguate, etc.

Comment: Check out the Wikipedia article on ***["text segmentation"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_segmentation)***.

Comment: Couldn't you just use regular expressions with predefined word rules? I'm sure there is plenty of code around for this.

Comment: A regular expression that can tell the difference between an apostrophe and a single quote? Nope.

Comment: Doable with unicode regex: http://www.regular-expressions.info/refunicode.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In English, you're fine with apostrophes. Compounds with hyphens, such as ice-cream, are mostly treated as separated tokens in corpora.
As for other languages in Europe, the "long" L in Catalan is denoted by a "bullet", e.g. `pel·lícula`.

Comment: In Catalan, sometimes a specific character `ĿL`/`ŀl` (occupying two spaces total) is used instead of an `l` and interpunct `L·L`/`l·l`. It is common to see a period used also (though this is prescriptively incorrect) `L.L`/`l.l`.

Comment: @tjfuke Yes, I think the ligature is even the preferred way.

Answer (score 3):

I think, the key point answering this question would be by understanding the **distinction between an *alphabet* and a *script***.

## Some boring definitions

[Alphabet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabet) is defined as a set of letters. Examples are *Latin*, *Cyrillic*, etc.

Script, or, more formally, [Writing system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Writing_system), is a *language-specific* set of rules used to encode a text in a particular language.

For each language, script includes (a part of) a certain *Alphabet*, certain type of *Numerals*, *Punctuation marks*, and other symbols.

## Now, let's get to the question

> With regard to English, is there any other symbols that can compose a word?

[English writing system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_writing_system) includes:

- Latin letters, letter-case and capital-case, obviously;
- [Arabic numerals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_numerals), obviously;
- [Diacritic marks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_terms_with_diacritical_marks) used for loanwords;
- [Punctuation symbols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punctuation_in_English) - make sure your software properly processes similarly looking symbols, e.g. apostrophes used to mark possession, and to mark contractions;
- For Natural Language Processing (NLP) software, you have to be aware that most characters with diacritic marks have their own Unicode points, so, for instance, parsing a sequence of `A` and ◌̂ (a zero-width *combining circumflex accent* modifier, U+0302, not to be confused with a standalone character `^`) should work exactly as parsing a single code point of `Â` (*Latin A with circumflex*)
- If you are parsing Unicode text, you have to be also aware about ligatures, [here's the list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_words_that_may_be_spelled_with_a_ligature), and there may be [stylistic ligatures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ligature_%28typography%29#Stylistic_ligatures) as well;

> Additionally, I would be interested in learning about other European languages and there use of such symbols within words which fall outside those defined by the alphabet.

Again, don't look into an *alphabet*. Look into *writing system* of a corresponding language.